# Convert struct pointer to another embedded struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct, stack

I am implementing a stack that does not require memory allocation and can take any struct as long as it embeds a special struct. Similar to [GNU's List](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/pspp-dev/2004-12/txtGDUqftYIk8.txt) implementation.

The struct that any struct must embed to work in the stack is:

```
struct stack_elem {
  struct stack_elem *next;
};
```

The struct that I would like to be used with the stack is:

```
struct node {
  double number;
  char character;
  int isNumber;
  struct stack_elem elem;
};
```

So the stack would look like this:

```
node:            node:
+---------+      +---------+
|number   |      |number   |
+---------+      +---------+
|character|      |character|
+---------+      +---------+
|isNumber |      |isNumber |
+---------+      +---------+
|elem     |      |elem     |
| *next   |----->| *next   |     
+---------+      +---------+ etc....
```

I am writing a macro called `stack_entry` to convert the embedded `elem` struct to its container `node` struct. Here's what I've tried so far. `stack_entry` will be used as follows:

```
struct stack_elem *top = peek(&stack);
struct node *converted_node = stack_entry(top, struct node, elem);
```

`stack_entry` will take a pointer to the `stack_elem`, the type of the node to be converted to and the name of the member field of the element in that node. I tried several ways to do it but none work. I realized that `STACK_ELEM` points to the `next` item and so I tried just subtracting the offset of `elem` from `struct node` and that did not work. Here are a few things I tried that did not work either:

```
#define stack_entry(STACK_ELEM, STRUCT, MEMBER)       \
         ((STRUCT *) &(STACK_ELEM) - offsetof (STRUCT, MEMBER))

#define stack_entry(STACK_ELEM, STRUCT, MEMBER)       \
         ((STRUCT *) ((uint8_t *) &(STACK_ELEM)->next \
         - offsetof (STRUCT, MEMBER)))
```

What would be the correct arithmetic? Why isn't subtracting the offset of `next`, hence the offset of `elem`, yielding node if its the last element in the struct?

GNU List `list_entry` macro is defined as:

```
#define list_entry(LIST_ELEM, STRUCT, MEMBER)           \
        ((STRUCT *) ((uint8_t *) &(LIST_ELEM)->next     \
                     - offsetof (STRUCT, MEMBER.next)))
```

How does this work? Why is `next` involved in here when its supposed to grab the container struct within the same node, and not the `next` one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GNU's `list_entry` works by subtracting the offset from the beginning of the struct to the `next` field from the address of the `next` field. It doesn't actually de-reference the `next` pointer. There is a common macro used for this in the Linux sources called [`container_of`](http://www.kroah.com/log/linux/container_of.html), which you might find helpful. The linked article is pretty informative.

In your second attempt to define `stack_entry`, you subtract the wrong offset (compare it to the GNU `list_entry` macro).

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation is actually not a stack but a singly linked list or a vector depending on whether your data structures can have arbitrary size or not.

Just for your consideration:

- why do you need a next pointer if your elements are the same size. shouldn't they all be in the same offset to each other? 
  Assume your structure is of size 16 bytes. the first element will be at address *base* and the next will be at address *base + 16* and the *n*-th element will be at *base + (n-1)* * *16* (Then you call it a vector)
- if your data structures have arbitrary size you need two things: some magic to find out which object it is and a *fixed* offset to where your next pointer will be. two good hints:

And the best thing for you: it has already been implemented by someone else: you can use `#include <sys/queue.h>` the `SLIST` then you just have to take care of on where to put your data.

Comment: well yes it is a linked stack, as opposed to an array stack. It is not a list since my implementation does not provide a way to iterate the nodes. It only provides push, pop and peek. Therefore, by definition, it is a stack.

And thanks for your points. I will consider them.